# How to uninstall Gnome Desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall, session

I installed the gnome desktop (not the shell) alongside the default Unity desktop but I decided to not use it as I prefer the Unity desktop. I want to uninstall gnome.
I already tried the `cd /usr/share/xsessions`

```
ls
sudo rm gnome.desktop
```

But it didn't remove the themes, packages, etc. It just removed it from the session option you'll get when you try to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If GUI is troubling you, login through CLI(**Ctrl+Alt+F1**)

Check if "`ppa-purge`" package is installed or not.

Run

```
dpkg -l | grep ppa-purge
```

If it returns the value, "**ppa-purge**" is installed. If not, install it as follows;

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

After that run the following commands;

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Reboot system and login through Unity.

Comment: When I ran the following commands:
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
I got this message "Could not find package list for ppa".